# Calling a Filter before a Servlet from REST Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest, servlets, servlet-filters

I have written a REST web service method `setToken(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response, @PathParam("token") String token)`, `HeaderFilter` and `SampleServlet`. Below is the web service class
`@Path("/service")
public class Service {

```
/*@Context 
private ServletContext servletContext; 

@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;

@Context
private HttpServletResponse response;*/


@Path("/val/{token}")   
@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
public String setToken(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response, @PathParam("token") String token) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String value=token;
    if(request==null){
        System.out.println("Request null");
    }
    System.out.println("Token: " + value);
    if(request!=null){
        request.setAttribute("param", value);
        Wrapper requestWrapper = new Wrapper(request);
        requestWrapper.addHeader("Authorization", token);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/secure").include(requestWrapper, response);
    }
    return "<token>"+ "<value>"+value+" token value"+"</value>" + "</token>";
}
```

}`

From the `setToken` web service method am calling `SampleServlet` using `request.getRequestDispatcher("/secure").include(request, response);` and the URL am using is http://localhost:8080/xxxx/xxxx/service/val/zzzz. zzzz is the value to be passed. The URL pattern for `HeaderFilter` and `SampleServlet` is /secure. Now the problem is `HeaderFilter` is not being called and directly 'SampleServlet' is called. Am I doing anything wrong???? Kindly help me get through this.

Comment: can you share your web.xml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The URL pattern for HeaderFilter and SampleServlet is /secure. Now the problem is HeaderFilter is not being called and directly 'SampleServlet' is called.

By default Filters are invoked only for requests originating from the web. They are not invoked for internal 'includes' and 'forwards'. To change the default behaviour and have the filter invoked, you will have to specify that in your filter-mapping element of web.xml

```
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>myfilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/secure</url-pattern>
   <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
   <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
   <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```