# Setting a Authorization Header in Filter

Tags: java, web-services, rest, servlets, servlet-filters

Am new to RESTful web service. I got a new requirement. Its like, I need to create a new RESTful Web Service where my service will accept a token from the calling program. This token needs to be set to Authorization Header and hit a filter which is in a JAR given by the client. I have created a RESTFul web service where it accepts a Token from calling program. now how can I set this token to Authorization Header. pls help me with this.

Comment: did you check  `javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders`?

Comment: Ya but i dint get a clear idea on `javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders`. Can u show me an example of this pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the context of this question the same as in this post of yours - [Calling a Filter before a Servlet from REST Webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816502/calling-a-filter-before-a-servlet-from-rest-webservice/32816871#32816871)

Then to summarize you have a Restful service accepting a token as a Header. You invoke a Filter from the service which provides some functionality and you need to pass the token to the filter as a request header?

To achieve that you need to create a [HttpServletRequestWrapper](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html) and pass that to the filter. You would override the getHeader(String name) method and

```
public class CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper implements HttpServletRequest{
       public CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request){
            super(request);
       }

       public String getHeader(String name){
            if(name.equals("AUTH-HEADER"){
                  //get the original request
                  HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)getRequest();
                   //now get it from the original request and return
            }else{
                  return request.getHeader(name);
             }
       }

      //  TODO override getHeaderNames()
}
```

And then pass this while invoking your filter.

```
 CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper(request);
 request.getRequestDispatcher("/secure").include(requestWrapper, response);
```

Answer (score 2):

In plain Java you can set the Authorization Header **Client side** this way:

```
String url = "test.com";
URL urlObj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "You Token");
```

**Edit**
Just to be sure i dont miss the topic of the op. 
If you want to crate an token for authorization you have to pass this token to the user after the user has logged in at you site. After the user client reveives the token the client have to send this token with every request (be shure you use ssl for transmission)

The **Serverside Code** should look like this:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException {
    String auth = req.getHeader("Authorization");
    //validate Token
}
```

Comment: I need to set the Authorization Header to `HttpServletRequest` in my case.

Comment: Hm i don't understand the problem the right way i think. You have a client and a server. The client sends a valid auth token to the server via the auth header. The server checks the token and do the desired request if the token is correct. The only time the server should send a token is when the user authenticate at the server<br/>If you receive the Token from the client at serverside it will be contained inside the `HttpServletRequest` if you want to sned it to the client you have to put it inside the `HttpServletResponse`

Comment: Its not Website. Just a Restful Web services. I need to create a Rest Web service. Third party will call by passing a token to my service. My service will receive the token and need to set to Authorization Header.

Comment: Okay if you received the token via the `HttpServletRequest` you can easily send it back with the `HttpServletResponse`. Just code something like `response.addHeader("Authorization", theToken);`

Comment: But I will get the token via Rest Web Service method as a String. Now I need to set to `HttpServletRequest`. That is where am stuck. pls let me know if you know how to set in `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: Okay lets keep it simple. If you are on the Serverside you cannot set anything at the `HttpServletRequest`because this is the object which holds the data the client has send you. If you want to send the token inside a header from the serverside to the client you have to put it inside the `HttpServletResponse`. This is for plain servlet technology. Or do you use the JAX RS api? Maybe its simpler if you show some of your serverside code you have done already.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do it like this:

```java
request.setAttribute("yourNameToken", yourToken);
```

then you can use the token with this script:

```java
String tk = (String) request.getAttribute("yourNameToken");
```