# Java: Filter when forwarding from servlet to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

is it possible to use a filter when forwarding a request from one servlet to another? In the web.xml of my project, I've tried this filter-mapping:

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Forwarding from servlet to JSP works fine. Forwarding from servlet to servlet doesn't call the filter. I wonder if I'm doing something wrong or it's just not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working in case of jsp because request goes to client and then comes back to server  but in case of servlet it is not redirected to client so your filter does not comes into picture there.

If you want then use sendRedirect instead of forward .

Check below link to see difference b/w sendRedirect and forward.

When you use SendRedirect container transfers the request to client or browser so url given inside the sendRedirect method is visible as a new request to the client.

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/sendredirect-forward-jsp-servlet.html#ixzz4QvHxSVFF

Comment: That's not right. Filters can be invoked for internal forwards as well. Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32816502/calling-a-filter-before-a-servlet-from-rest-webservice/32816871#32816871

Comment: have u tried it bcz in question he used same as the link but it not working .

Comment: Yes. Why else would there be dispatcher element with values as 'FORWARD' and 'INCLUDE'. Read more 1. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/cweb_sfilt.html
2. https://coderanch.com/t/362000/java/Filters-Dispatchers
3. http://otndnld.oracle.co.jp/document/products/as10g/101300/B25221_03/web.1013/b14426/filters.htm#BCFIHAEA

Comment: I think It got somehting to do with servlet version too .

Java Servlet Specification 2.4 enables you to define a new 
<dispatcher> element in the deployment descriptor with possible values such as REQUEST, FORWARD, INCLUDE, ERROR, instead of invoking filters with RequestDispatcher.

Java Servlet Specification 3.0 enables you to define a new 

<dispatcher> element in the deployment descriptor with possible values such as ASYNC, REQUEST, FORWARD, INCLUDE, ERROR, instead of invoking filters with RequestDispatcher.